# Operator overload c++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I need to overload this operator (mainMenu is class type called 'Menu'):

```
if (mainMenu) {
    cout << "The mainMenu is valid and usable." << endl;
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
bool operator!(const Menu& lobj);
```

Answer (score 7):

In the condition of this if statement

```
if (mainMenu)
```

the logical negation operator `!` is not used.

Instead you could write for example

```
if ( !!mainMenu )
```

However it is better to declare an explicit conversion operator like

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

In this case you could write

```
if (mainMenu)
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows a difference between these operators.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    bool operator !() const
    {
        return false;
    }

    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    if ( !!A() ) std::cout << "Hello\n";

    if ( A() ) std::cout << "World!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
World!
```